# Fit image to browser size in CSS

Tags: css, image, browser

I’m struggling withthis of few hours new, and can’t get it right. My CSS skills a pure, so please understand.

So what I want to achieve is I have image on web site and when I change size of the browser window, image size has to adjust to a browser size, so whole image can be seen. Also image has to be in the center of the page.
Thanks for any help.

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<title>James Laycock</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
<div id="image_container">
<a href="index.php?page=1"><img src="images/01.jpg" class="image" /></a></div>
</div></div></body></html>
```

style.css:

```
body{
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
padding-top: 10px;
text-align: center;}

#main {
height: 90%;
width: 1000px;
position: absolute;
border: 0px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;}

#content{
height: 90%;
width: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right:10px;}

#image_container{
height: 100%;
max-height:100%;
width: auto;}

.image{
height: 100%; 
width: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting on the image container

> text-align: center

And, on the actual image put height/width in percentage.

Edit: don't forget also centering the image container, or setting it's width to full screen.